# Captioning a table within a cell

Tags: tables, captions

This code below produces the following table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{1.175\linewidth}{c|*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}\toprule
    \multicolumn{6}{c} {\makecell{\textit{Number of dendrograms in each group for 10,000 bootstrap samples }}} \\
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{1}{c} {\makecell{G1}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c} {\makecell{G2}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c} {\makecell{G3}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c} {\makecell{G4}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c} {\makecell{G5}}  \\
    \midrule
    \hline
    \# of Subgroups & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 5\\
    \# of Dendrograms & 63 & 15 & 6 & 5 & 1\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{}
    \label{table:prosConsOptionalApproaches}
\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How would I add the caption of this table next to 'Number of dendrograms....'. i.e within the top cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- it is not clear why you defined 11 columns but use only 6
- the use of the `makecell` in your table are superfluous
- use of `\multicolumn{1}{c}{....}` can only cause a problems (if the column headers is wider than column width). they are superfluous
- i wouldn't put caption inside cell, rather only add `\toprule` above it and use standard form of caption
- partly considering [Bernard's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) answer, your code can be reduced to:

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
  \usepackage{booktabs, ltablex, makecell}
  \usepackage{caption}

  \begin{document}

  \keepXColumns
  \setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}%1.175
  \toprule
  \addlinespace
  \captionsetup{textfont=it, skip=0.25ex}
      \caption{Number of dendrograms in each group for 10,000 bootstrap samples}
      \label{table:prosConsOptionalApproaches}\\
      \midrule
                          & G1 & G2 & G3 & G4 & G5 \\
      \midrule
      \midrule
      \# of Subgroups     &  0 &  0 &  2 &  0 &  5 \\
      \# of Dendrograms   & 63 & 15 &  6 &  5 &  1 \\
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}

  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. Your answer really helped me for all my other tables too. Also what line or command in particular tells LaTeX to use all 6 columns for the caption? I think I created 6 columns for the top row so that the caption is spread over them.

Comment: @Ali, you not need to tell this to table,of course if you use `ltablex` package. otherwise, you need to enclose caption in a ˙\parbox˛` as suggest egreg in his answer or use `\multicolumn` on the following way: `multicolumn{6}{p{\linewidth}{\caption{...}}`.

Answer (score 3):

As it is the way longtable works, you can load the `ltablex` package, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. Here is a code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ltablex, makecell, booktabs, caption}

\begin{document}

\keepXColumns
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%1.175
\toprule
    \multicolumn{6}{c} {\makecell{\textit{Number of dendrograms in each group for 10,000 bootstrap samples }}} \\[1ex]
\captionsetup{labelsep=none}
   \caption{}
    \label{table:prosConsOptionalApproaches}\\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    & \multicolumn{1}{c} {\makecell{G1}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c} {\makecell{G2}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c} {\makecell{G3}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c} {\makecell{G4}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c} {\makecell{G5}} \\
    \midrule
    \midrule
    \# of Subgroups & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 5\\
    \# of Dendrograms & 63 & 15 & 6 & 5 & 1\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

*Note*: I reduced the size to `tabularx` to `\linewidth`, as this is a different problem. If you want a centred tabularx, wider than `\textwidth`, nest in an `adjustwidth` environment, from `changepage`
[image]

Comment: I think @Zarko's answer minimises the amount of code necessary. i.e deleting the `makecell` and multicolumns. But thank you, your answer has been helpful for other tables where long table is necessary

Answer (score 1):

Use a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{
  c
  *{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{
  \caption{Number of dendrograms in each
    group for 10,000 bootstrap samples}%
  \label{table:prosConsOptionalApproaches}%
}} \\
\midrule
    & G1 & G2 & G3 & G4 & G5 \\
\midrule
\# of Subgroups & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 5\\
\# of Dendrograms & 63 & 15 & 6 & 5 & 1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I've removed all the `makecell` settings besides vertical and double rules.

[image]